# How can i change the code to my own country timezone?

Tags: javascript

```
function timeleft(eventTime) {
    var now = new Date(); 
    var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
    var event_time = new Date(eventTime);


    var t1 = now_utc.getTime();
    //removes one hour from the date - 60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 miliseconds - -60*60*1000
    var t2 = event_time.getTime();
    var time_left = new Date(parseInt(t2-t1));
    if(time_left<0) {
        return "00:00:00:00";
    }
    msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    days = Math.floor(time_left/msPerDay);
    if (days < 10) { days = "0"+days; }
    hours = time_left.getUTCHours();
    if (hours < 10) { hours = "0"+hours;}
    minutes = time_left.getUTCMinutes();
    if (minutes < 10) { minutes = "0"+minutes; }
    seconds = time_left.getUTCSeconds();
    if (seconds < 10) { seconds = "0"+seconds; }

    return(days+":"+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
}
```

this is the full code below

```
/*
 * jquery-counter plugin
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 *
 * http://docs.jquery.com/License
 */

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.simple_countdown_timer').each(function() {     
        countdown(jQuery('#'+jQuery(this).attr('id')+' .sct_count'),{
            eventTime: jQuery('#'+jQuery(this).attr('id')+' .sct_event_time').text(),
            image: jQuery('#'+jQuery(this).attr('id')+' .sct_image').text(),
        });
    });
});

function countdown(sct_div_id,userOptions)
{
  // Default options
  var options = {
    stepTime: 60,
    // startTime and format MUST follow the same format.
    // also you cannot specify a format unordered (e.g. hh:ss:mm is wrong)
    format: "dd:hh:mm:ss",
    eventTime: "Jan, 1, 2013, 00:00",
    digitImages: 6,
    digitWidth: 13,
    digitHeight: 19,
    timerEnd: function(){},
    image: "http://cdn.live-nhl.com/media-resources/other/countdown-timer/digits-13-19.png"
  };
  var digits = [], interval;

  userOptions.startTime = timeleft(userOptions.eventTime);

  // Draw digits in given container
  var createDigits = function(where) 
  {
    var c = 0;
    var tempStartTime = options.startTime;
    // Iterate each startTime digit, if it is not a digit
    // we'll asume that it's a separator
    for (var i = 0; i < options.startTime.length; i++)
    {
      if (parseInt(tempStartTime.charAt(i)) >= 0) 
      {
        elem = jQuery('<div id="cnt_' + i + '" class="cntDigit" />').css({
          height: options.digitHeight * options.digitImages * 10, 
          float: 'left', background: 'url(\'' + options.image + '\')',
          width: options.digitWidth});
        digits.push(elem);
        margin(c, -((parseInt(tempStartTime.charAt(i)) * options.digitHeight *
                              options.digitImages)));
        digits[c].__max = 9;
        // Add max digits, for example, first digit of minutes (mm) has 
        // a max of 5. Conditional max is used when the left digit has reach
        // the max. For example second "hours" digit has a conditional max of 3         

        switch (options.format.charAt(i)) {
          case 'h':
            digits[c].__max = (c % 2 == 0) ? 2: 9;
            if (c % 2 != 0)
              digits[c].__condmax = 3;
            break;
          case 'd': 
            digits[c].__max = 9;
            break;
          case 'm':
          case 's':
            digits[c].__max = (c % 2 == 0) ? 5: 9;
        }
        ++c;
      }
      else 
        elem = jQuery('<div class="cntDescSeparator"/>').css({float: 'left'})
                .text(options.format.charAt(i-1));

            where.append('<div>');
            where.append(elem);
            where.append('</div>');
    }
        elem = jQuery('<div class="cntDescSeparator"/>').css({float: 'left'})
                .text('s');

            where.append('<div>');
            where.append(elem);
            where.append('</div>');
  };

  // Set or get element margin
  var margin = function(elem, val) 
  {
    if (val !== undefined)
      return digits[elem].css({'marginTop': val + 'px'});

    return parseInt(digits[elem].css('marginTop').replace('px', ''));
  };

  // Makes the movement. This is done by "digitImages" steps.
  var moveStep = function(elem) 
  {
    digits[elem]._digitInitial = -(digits[elem].__max * options.digitHeight * options.digitImages);
    return function _move() {
      mtop = margin(elem) + options.digitHeight;
      if (mtop == options.digitHeight) {
        margin(elem, digits[elem]._digitInitial);
        if (elem > 0) moveStep(elem - 1)();
        else 
        {
          clearInterval(interval);
          for (var i=0; i < digits.length; i++) margin(i, 0);
          options.timerEnd();
          var match_link = digits[elem].parent().parent().parent().children('.match-link').attr('href');
          digits[elem].parent().parent().html('<a href="'+match_link+'" class="live-now"><img width="145" height="35" src="http://cdn.live-nhl.com/media-resources/other/WatchNow.png" class="attachment-medium" alt="WatchNow" title="WatchNow"></a>');

          return;
        }
        if ((elem > 0) && (digits[elem].__condmax !== undefined) && 
            (digits[elem - 1]._digitInitial == margin(elem - 1)))
          margin(elem, -(digits[elem].__condmax * options.digitHeight * options.digitImages));
        return;
      }

      margin(elem, mtop);
      if (margin(elem) / options.digitHeight % options.digitImages != 0)
        setTimeout(_move, options.stepTime);

      if (mtop == 0) digits[elem].__ismax = true;
    }
  };

  jQuery.extend(options, userOptions);
  sct_div_id.css({height: options.digitHeight, overflow: 'hidden'});
  createDigits(sct_div_id);
  interval = setInterval(moveStep(digits.length - 1), 1000);
}

function timeleft(eventTime) {
    var now = new Date(); 
    var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
    var event_time = new Date(eventTime);


    var t1 = now_utc.getTime();
    //removes one hour from the date - 60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 miliseconds - -60*60*1000
    var t2 = event_time.getTime();
    var time_left = new Date(parseInt(t2-t1));
    if(time_left<0) {
        return "00:00:00:00";
    }
    msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    days = Math.floor(time_left/msPerDay);
    if (days < 10) { days = "0"+days; }
    hours = time_left.getUTCHours();
    if (hours < 10) { hours = "0"+hours;}
    minutes = time_left.getUTCMinutes();
    if (minutes < 10) { minutes = "0"+minutes; }
    seconds = time_left.getUTCSeconds();
    if (seconds < 10) { seconds = "0"+seconds; }

    return(days+":"+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
}
```

link my website: https://www.livenflgames.com/

Answer (score 0):

Javascript gets date from the machine its running on.
Check [W3schools reference on date methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp)

```
var now = new Date();
```

Comment: can i set specific country date time. in the code are set only UTC time. i want to Set UTC+6 date time? it is possible bro?

Comment: W3Schools isn't a very good reference. For example, they make no mention of [`getTimezoneOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset).

Answer (score 0):

you are store the time in database unix timestamp and convert it client side according client timezone by java-script Date Function.
[unix timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) supported by javascript